# Prevent unrolling for a specific loop

Tags: c++, loops

So there is already a question on how to tell the compiler to unroll a specific loop.

I have a project that uses too many templates and I run out of memory when I try to iterate over a specific place in the code. (This happens also for the non-iterated code when I have a browser window open for example.)

My best guess is that the compiler tries to unroll this loop and compilation fails due to memory exhaustion. How would I tell the compiler not to try to unroll that loop?

I'm using g++-4.7.

Comment: Sounds like the wrong solution to me. Are you sure it's unrolling in the first place? Maybe simplifying/breaking up the code in some way is the more appropriate solution?

Comment: I agree with Mats.  Do you have by any chance some recursive templates (using some integral parameters) ?

Comment: yes, the pre-existing code is full of templates. @Mats Petersson: I am not sure it is unrolling, I will edit my question for that.

I am (was) new to templates before that project. If there is any technique to help the compiler deal with heavilly templated code please share - I see it is a common problem but I didn't find a straightforward solution yet.

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar question here: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56746.  Apparently using -save-temps options helps.

Comment: Thank you Cruentus_Nex! That is a very helpful comment! If nobody answers in a couple of days I will consider this as the answer. I would be really interested if you could also give an outline of what is happening and why that helps here for reference.

Comment: Well, -save-temps saves pre-processed intermediate files permanently in the current directory, so my thought is that GCC pre-processes them, dumps them in the directory then, grabs them up for the compilation stage, instead of doing it all at once with its internal pre-processor, effectively splitting compilation up into another stage. So this basically just  forces a separation between pre-processes and compilation.  You may be able to do the same thing with -no-integrated-cpp btw.